# How can I optimize an if request with many many "or" operators?

Tags: php, if-statement

Is there a way to reduce the code if I have many "ands" and "ands" in my if request for the same value? I would like to need `$row['animal']` only one time:

```
  if ($row['animal'] == "cat") or 
     ($row['animal'] == "dog") or 
     ($row['animal'] == "bird") or 
     ($row['animal'] == "monkey") or 
     ($row['animal'] == "mouse") or 
     ($row['animal'] == "hedgehog"){
     echo "many animals";}
```

Comment: Use an array and `in_array()`. That's for `or` by the way, you code with `and`'s doesn't make any sense; it will always return `false`...

Comment: Can a row be an Cat and a dog at The same time?

Answer (score 0):

```
echo in_array($row['animal'], array('cat', 'dog', 'bird', 'monkey', 'mouse','hedgehog'))
      ? 'many animals' 
      : 'no animals';
```